# Написать функцию-шаблон поиска максимального элемента в очереди

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Добрый день. Помогите отыскать ошибку в коде. Нужно написать функцию-шаблон для поиска максимального элемента в очереди (элементы очереди отличаются типами данных). Написал функцию, но выкидывает не совсем понятные ошибки, касающиеся функции findMax(). Только начал осваивать эту тему, самостоятельно не получилось разобраться. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void fillArray(queue<T> &arr)
{
    T el;
    int size;
    cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> el;
        arr.push(el);
    }
}

template <typename T>
T findMax(queue<T> arr)
{
    T maxValue = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}


int main()
{
    queue<int> IntArr;
    queue<double> doubleArr;

    fillArray(IntArr);
    fillArray(doubleArr);
    cout << "Max in IntArr: " << findMax(IntArr) << endl;
    cout << "Max in DoubleArr: " << findMax(doubleArr) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *не совсем понятные ошибки* - так приведите их тут

Comment: с очереди элементы вытащить можно только с головы, нет доступа ко всем элементам

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть на [std::priority_queue](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), а так же на `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap`. Ну и искать лучше в `std::vector`, а не в `queue`.

Comment: Нам векторами нельзя пользоваться. Надо самому функцию написать

Answer (score 1):

У очереди НЕТ возможности обращения к элементам наподобие `arr[i]`.

Так что, по большому счету, найти максимальный элемент в очереди можно только вынимая элемент в начале очереди, сравнивая и ставя его снова в конец очереди...

Ну, или, раз уж вы передаете очередь не по ссылке, а по значению:

```
T findMax(queue<T> arr)
```

то все равно это копия, так что можно просто выбрать из очереди все элементы для поиска максимального, не возвращая их в очередь.